# Can anyone explain this TypeScript "export" statement?

Tags: typescript

I couldn't understand this code.

```
function MappableMixin<T extends Constructor<Model<MappableTraits>>>(Base: T) {
   ...
   ...   
}

namespace MappableMixin {
   ...
}

export default MappableMixin;
```

I see two "MappableMixin" identifiers in this file.
Actually, what does this file export? function or namespace?
Code link is [here](https://github.com/TerriaJS/terriajs/blob/00ee7b242635ff7c4e542c2285f35cae23ee715b/lib/ModelMixins/MappableMixin.ts#L202)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code in the question itself, rather than just a picture, as noted it [ask], "**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question."

Answer (score 0):

The answer is both. The code generating the namespace actually checks if the namespace variable is already defined. If so it attaches the namespace members to eh existing value.

So this TS code:

```
function MappableMixin() {

}
namespace MappableMixin {
  export function isMixedInto(model: any): boolean {
    return true
  }
}
```

becomes in JS:

```js
function MappableMixin() {
}
(function (MappableMixin) {
    function isMixedInto(model) {
        return true;
    }
    MappableMixin.isMixedInto = isMixedInto;
})(MappableMixin || (MappableMixin = {}));
export default MappableMixin;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWQIYAd2oEYBsCmyMAHjGABQCUiA3gFB0C+dYqAtvgM5YT4oZY8hEmVp1EifMXRwATlEShIsBIhicixfABMAkmChxybONvy4AXIlRgAnpSvY4cAjbESJs-FBCykUWRB8cURmZjopGXlEM2BUEFwFNEwcAk0yAG4gA)

As you can see in the JS code, there is a self executing function taht atatches the namespace members to the parameter, with the argument passed in being `MappableMixin || (MappableMixin = {})`. So since `MappableMixin` is already defined as a function a new object for the namespace will not be created, and the `MappableMixin` will be used as the container for the namespace members.